# Proving that $\tan^n\angle A + \tan^n\angle B + \tan^n\angle C \ge 3 + \frac{3n}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> Given a acute $\triangle ABC$. Prove that $$\tan^n\angle A + \tan^n\angle B + \tan^n\angle C \ge  3 + \dfrac{3n}{2}$$

I have tried by using a inductive proof.

In case $n=0$, the equality holds.

In case $n=1$, we can prove that $\tan\angle A + \tan\angle B + \tan\angle C \ge  3\sqrt3>\frac92$.

- Use AM-GM inequality, we obtain:
  $$\tan A+\tan B+\tan C\ge3\sqrt[3]{\tan A\tan B\tan C}=3\sqrt[3]{\tan A+\tan B+\tan C}$$
  Hence, we have Q.E.D

However, I think that by using this way, I can't prove my problem.

---

Any **Hint**? Or any solution which is simplier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$ f(x)=\tan(x)^n$ is a convex function on $I=\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, hence by Jensen's inequality:
$$ \sum_{cyc}\tan^n A \geq 3\left(\tan\frac{\pi}{3}\right)^n = 3\sqrt{3}^n$$
so it is enough to prove that $\sqrt{3}^n \geq 1+\frac{n}{2}$, but that follows from Bernoulli's inequality since $\sqrt{3}>1+\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: induction and rearrangement inequality.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?